# How to set label text to a variable as the view loads?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

So I have this little project in which the user goes from one view to another as they click buttons, and the text on the last button they've clicked should show up in a label in the top of the screen. I figured out how to have the variables accessible from anywhere in the app, and also how to change it as the user presses the buttons. Yet, I can only make the label's text change once a button is hit, and I wanted it to happen automatically (the view to appear with the label already containing the correct text).

For that I set the label in two different ways (which I found online):

```
@interface ViewMateria : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *materiaLabel;
}
@end
```

and

```
@interface ViewMateria : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutput UILabel *materiaLabel;

@end
```

Still, for both of this I can not access the label by a simple `materiaLabel.text` or anything like that, and can't find a way to do it without the need for the press of a button.

I've been looking for an answer for this for a while now, and nothing that I found seemed to be of use for me (since most of the links I found taught how to change a label text with the press of a button).

This is my first project with Objective-C and Xcode, and I don't really know the answer, so maybe I am missing something quite obvious, but still, if anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .h file for the view controller:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutput UILabel *materiaLabel;
```

When you are about to present the view controller, access it like this:

```
your_ViewMateria_object.materiaLabel.text = @"";
```

Then present it..

Are you using segues?

If yes, its another story..

**UPDATE:**

For segues use this, with the .h property value I just mentioned:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
        ViewMateria *vm = [segue destinationViewController];
        vm.materiaLabel.text = @"Whatever";
}
```

You should be good to go now ;D

Did it work?

Comment: `@implementation ViewMateria

your_ViewMateria_object.materiaLabel.text = [variableStorage sharedInstance].Materia;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}`

This is what my ViewMateria looks like, and two problems keep appearing:
1 - Unknown type name 'your_ViewMateria_object'
2 - Expected identifier or '('

By the way, sorry, I mixed up my self, I am not using Segues

Comment: is IBOutput similar to IBOutlet? What is this IBOutput?

Comment: Also, the @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutput UILabel *materiaLabel; keeps giving me 4 errors and one warning, one of which is `"Cannot declare variable inside @interface or @protocol"`

Comment: I would really suggest reading\watching some introductions, on youtube or anything, before diving into deep stuff... I recommend looking at sample codes too. Your questions shows that you didn't read anything about view controllers. It will become super easy if you just looked up some tutorials. Good luck.

Comment: @AugustoQ hi from my understanding you are trying to send the text from the button to second view controller and set this text to a label in the second view controller right?

Comment: @AravindBG, that is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

In second view controller .h file

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *buttonName;`

.m file

`self.materiaLabel.text =  self.buttonName;`

In first view controller .m file

inside `IBAction`

```
secondviewcontrollerObject.buttonName = [(UIButton *)sender currentTitle];
```

Comment: I keep getting two error messages: `Expected identifier` and `Use of undeclared identifier 'SecondViewControllerObject'` Is there any other setup I need o do?

Comment: You have to create an object of second view controller in first view controller, that is what i meant by secondviewcontrollerObject.